# JFrame close operation

Tags: java, jframe, operation

How can I set another close operation for my JFrame besides the myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ?
Example: I got a start() and a stop() method and I want the stop() to be called before the JFrame exits ( stop() saves my files and joins the Thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `WindowListener` to your `JFrame` and implement the `windowClosing()` event:

```
// Use WindowAdapter if you don't want to implement the rest of the methods
// otherwise use new WindowListener()
window.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() { 
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        stop();
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the [dispose](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) method.

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
  this.stop();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Where would the dispose methos be, in the class that extends JFrame?

Comment: Yeppers, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html extends Window... Therefore you can override it in your class that extends jframe